# XML to ARRAY to JSON to ng-repeat

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs, json, xml

I am getting data from an API that returns in XML.

I am converting this to a PHP array and running it through a foreach.

This then goes into a new array, which gets changed into json.

I'm then sending this to angularjs to be put into a ng-repeat for a form select.

My problem is when I try to put it in the ng-repeat I get a duplication error.

**$http method calling the php script**

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'assets/scripts/domains.php',
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
        domains.tlds = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('Error!');
    });
```

**php script calling the API**

```
<?php

   require 'vendor/autoload.php';

   Requests::register_autoloader();

   $response = Requests::get('api_url_hidden_for_security');

   $xml = simplexml_load_string($response->body);
   $json = json_encode($xml);
   $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

   $result = $array['tlds'];

   $array = array();

   foreach ($result as $extension) {
      $name = $extension['tld'];
      $active = $extension['active'];
      $array[] = array('title' => $name, 'active' => $extension['active']);
   }

   $content = json_encode($array);

   var_dump($content);
```

**ng-repeat for final product**

```
<select ng-model="domains.tld" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected disabled>--Choose TLD--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="option in domains.tlds" ng-if="option.active == 1" value="{{option.title}}">{{option.title}}</option>
</select>
```

**initial untouched response from api (partial) ($xml in php script)**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (7) { ["command"]=> string(1) "0" ["error_code"]=> string(1) "0" ["ttl"]=> string(5) "56000" ["tlds"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#719 (69) { ["com"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#720 (16) { ["tld"]=> string(3) "com" ["years"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#789 (10) { ["n0"]=> string(1) "1" ["n1"]=> string(1) "2" ["n2"]=> string(1) "3" ["n3"]=> string(1) "4" ["n4"]=> string(1) "5" ["n5"]=> string(1) "6" ["n6"]=> string(1) "7" ["n7"]=> string(1) "8" ["n8"]=> string(1) "9" ["n9"]=> string(2) "10" } ["renewal"]=> string(1) "1" ["transfer"]=> string(1) "1" ["registrar_lock"]=> string(1) "1" ["id_protect"]=> string(1) "1" ["epp"]=> string(1) "1" ["whois"]=> string(1) "1" ["description"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#790 (0) { } ["refund_price"]=> string(2) "12" ["specialdnsreg"]=> string(1) "0" ["rgp"]=> string(1) "1" ["check_registrar"]=> string(8) "verisign" ["registrar"]=> string(8) "verisign" ["extra_attributes"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#791 (0) { } ["active"]=> string(1) "1" } ["net"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#721 (16) { ["tld"]=> string(3) "net" ["years"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#791 (10) { ["n0"]=> string(1) "1" ["n1"]=> string(1) "2" ["n2"]=> string(1) "3" ["n3"]=> string(1) "4" ["n4"]=> string(1) "5" ["n5"]=> string(1) "6" ["n6"]=> string(1) "7" ["n7"]=> string(1) "8" ["n8"]=> string(1) "9" ["n9"]=> string(2) "10" } ["renewal"]=> string(1) "1" ["transfer"]=> string(1) "1" ["registrar_lock"]=> string(1) "1"
```

**final response from php script** (complete) ($content in php script)

```
string(2058) "[{"title":"com","active":"1"},{"title":"net","active":"1"},{"title":"org","active":"1"},{"title":"info","active":"1"},{"title":"biz","active":"1"},{"title":"us","active":"1"},{"title":"uk","active":"1"},{"title":"co.uk","active":"1"},{"title":"ca","active":"1"},{"title":"eu","active":"1"},{"title":"com.au","active":"1"},{"title":"website","active":"1"},{"title":"we.bs","active":"1"},{"title":"space","active":"1"},{"title":"co","active":"1"},{"title":"ae","active":"1"},{"title":"qa","active":"1"},{"title":"co.za","active":"1"},{"title":"ru","active":"1"},{"title":"es","active":"1"},{"title":"me","active":"1"},{"title":"tv","active":"1"},{"title":"xyz","active":"1"},{"title":"top","active":"1"},{"title":"pro","active":"1"},{"title":"company","active":"1"},{"title":"solutions","active":"1"},{"title":"services","active":"1"},{"title":"deals","active":"1"},{"title":"in","active":"1"},{"title":"de","active":"1"},{"title":"it","active":"1"},{"title":"nl","active":"1"},{"title":"fr","active":"1"},{"title":"co.il","active":"1"},{"title":"ch","active":"1"},{"title":"se","active":"1"},{"title":"co.nz","active":"1"},{"title":"pl","active":"1"},{"title":"ph","active":"1"},{"title":"jp","active":"1"},{"title":"club","active":"1"},{"title":"news","active":"1"},{"title":"name","active":"1"},{"title":"mobi","active":"1"},{"title":"cc","active":"1"},{"title":"ws","active":"1"},{"title":"be","active":"1"},{"title":"mx","active":"1"},{"title":"com.mx","active":"1"},{"title":"org.uk","active":"1"},{"title":"me.uk","active":"1"},{"title":"net.au","active":"1"},{"title":"org.au","active":"1"},{"title":"at","active":"1"},{"title":"nu","active":"1"},{"title":"asia","active":"1"},{"title":"net.nz","active":"1"},{"title":"org.nz","active":"1"},{"title":"cn","active":"1"},{"title":"com.cn","active":"1"},{"title":"net.cn","active":"1"},{"title":"org.cn","active":"1"},{"title":"tw","active":"1"},{"title":"com.tw","active":"1"},{"title":"org.tw","active":"1"},{"title":"idv.tw","active":"1"},{"title":"host","active":"0"},{"title":"hosting","active":"0"}]"
```

**Error code provided from angularjs**

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: option in domains.tlds, Duplicate key: string:r, Duplicate value: r
```

Basically I want my workflow to work like so:

1. AngularJS Calls php Script.
2. Php script calls api.
3. PHP script transform api response from xml to json and sends back to angularjs
4. AngularJS uses response to generate a form select using ng-repeat.